# How to apply a function to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I have an assignment that sounds like:

**Computer put two arrays with random strings in Test.data. Need a single list which contains one element from a, then one from b, and so forth.**

**Example:**

```
a: ['a', 'b', 'c']    
b: ['d', 'e']    
-> ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']
```

I tried this code, but it simply replaces the data that is in the Test.data.

```
Test.data = function arry(a, b) {
const c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(a[i]);
    }

    if (b[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(b[i]);
    }
}
}
```

The mistake is how I apply the function to the object, but I do not know how to solve it

Comment: _Apply the function to the object_. Which object?

Comment: what is TEST object?

Comment: @ShubhamJain this is the object in which the array a and b

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Test.data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do?

```
function arry(a, b) {
    const c = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
        if (a[i] != undefined) {
            c.push(a[i]);
        }

        if (b[i] != undefined) {
            c.push(b[i]);
        }
    }
    return c;
}

let alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let beta = ['d', 'e'];
Test.data = arry(alpha, beta)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to clean up your code, hopefully it helps

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
b = ['d', 'e'];

function Test(a, b)
{
    var c = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] !== undefined)
        {
            c.push(a[i]);
        }

        if (b[i] !== undefined)
        {
            c.push(b[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(c);
}

Test(a, b);
```